# scp+ssh+scp in a single connection

Tags: ssh, scp, ssh-tunneling

I don't know the nomenclature, but basically our corporate environment is setup with jumphosts so creating an ssh tunnel is really slow. Therefore I'm hoping there is some way to perform these three steps in a single ssh command:

```bsh
$ scp localfile.jar user@server:~/path/ # upload executable
$ ssh user@server java -jar path/localfile.jar some argument >path/output.bin # run it
$ scp user@server:~/path/output.bin . # download output
```

This is the way. Is there a way? (The server doesn't have access to my local machine, but perhaps that is stating the obvious.) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Unless it's been specifically disabled you could try multiplexing. This is still several commands, but as it uses just the initial master connection for the authentication with the remaining commands run over that pre-authenticated channel, you should find it runs more quickly:

```
# Set up master connection to target system
ssh -S "$HOME/.ssh.sock" -M -o ControlPersist=yes -fN user@server

# Perform the commands using the master connection
scp -o ControlPath="$HOME/.ssh.sock" localfile.jar user@server:path/
ssh -S "$HOME/.ssh.sock" user@server java -jar path/localfile.jar some argument >path/output.bin

# Tear down the master connection when you have finished
ssh -S "$HOME/.ssh.sock" -O exit user@server
```

You don't need the last command from your example set of three because your `ssh` command already puts its output into the *local* file `path/output.bin`.

You can specify a timeout for the master session, so that if you stop using it and forget to close it down it will end automatically (for example, `ControlPersist=60` instead of `ControlPersist=yes` for a minute-long timeout).

If you perform these operations frequently it may be worth using your `~/.ssh/ssh_config` to redefine your preferred default settings for the target `server`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where the *jumphost* falls into your picture, but those 3 commands can be done with:

```
< localfile.jar gzip -3 |
  ssh user@server '
    gunzip > path/localfile.jar &&
      java -jar path/localfile.jar some argument | gzip -3
' | gunzip > output.bin
```

Where that `localfile.jar` is fed compressed on the stdin of `ssh`, which will be forwarded to the stdin of the remote shell, and eventually `gunzip` which dumps it in a remote file.

Similarly the output of `java` is sent compressed on stdout, and decompressed on the fly locally to store on the local `output.bin`.

Answer (score -1):

sh+expect

1. Write an `sh` script with all three your commands as they are - you will still have to enter your password three times, but it still would be easier to do comparing with manual commands.
2. Once you have a script, you can play with `expect` and fill the password with it. But that can be deemed insecure, since with `expect` you have to store passwords openly in the script.

Personally I often stop on the first solution - type my password several times is not very hard (just annoying). But if security environment allows - `expect` can do wonders/